# How to declare an array in a new type?

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to declare an array within the Computer type as in the following code

```
Add-Type @"
public struct Computer {
    public string Name;
    public string ProductName;
    # declare array
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To declare a field of type string array in C#:

```
public string[] YourArrayName
```

Comment: Thanks, I spent ages trying to do a powershell declaration inside the C# code :)